# jQuery validate - validate() not being called

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I am trying to use jQuery validation on a page in my application, but the validate() function I've written doesn't get called and the form is always submitted. Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

Here is the source of my page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
    <body data-root="/" style="overflow-y:auto">
        <div class="main">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                    <script type="text/javascript">
                        $(function () {
                            $("#formCreateInvoice").validate({
                                rules: {
                                    FirstName: {
                                        required: true,
                                        maxLength: 255
                                    },
                                    Surname: {
                                        required: true,
                                        maxLength: 255
                                    }
                                },
                                messages: {
                                    FirstName: {
                                        required: "Please enter a first name",
                                        maxLength: "The entered value is too long (must be no more than 255 characters)"
                                    },
                                    Surname: {
                                        required: "Please enter a surname",
                                        maxLength: "The entered value is too long (must be no more                 than 255 characters)"
                                    },
                                }
                            });
                        });
                    </script>

                    <form action="/Order/CreateSelfPay" id="formCreateInvoice" method="post">    <div class="panel panel-default">
                            <div class="panel-body">
                                <div class="row filters">
                                    <div class="form-group col-sm-4">
                                        <label for="SearchFirstName">First name</label>
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control " id="SearchFirstName">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group col-sm-4">
                                        <label for="SearchSurname">Surname</label>
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="SearchSurname">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="modal-footer">
                                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">
                                        Clear <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span>
                                    </button>
                                    <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">
                                        Create invoice <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-                right"></span>
                                    </button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script src="/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js"></script>

    </body>
</html>
```

Any help greatly appreciated.

M

Comment: @GauravKalyan he is, the `$(function() { })` construct is equivalent to the DOMReady handler.

Comment: My validation is now working, thanks a lot! I'm a happy bunny.

Answer (score 1):

The validate framework uses name to identify the fields, so you need to specify `name` attribute to the elements.

```
<input type="text" class="form-control " id="SearchFirstName" name="FirstName">
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="SearchSurname" name="SurName">
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, gonna try this out

Comment: My validation is now working, thanks a lot! I'm a happy bunny.